# Rails ActiveAdmin: Routed to /admin/admin/my_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I would like to access the admin index page for a given resource:
The URL in the link is correct.

[image: chrome inspector shcreenshot]

When I click on the link though, I get the following routing error[image]

Here is how the admin file looks like:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register GardenPillarsDomain::BasePrice,
  as: 'garden_pillars_base_prices' do
    permit_params :section, :laying_type, :max_height, :constructor_price, :sales_margin
    menu false
  end
```

And here is how the tab I click on to trigger the error is declared in the `active_admin.rb` initializer

```rb
menu.add label: "Some Label" do |menu|
  menu.add label: I18n.t("active_admin.garden_pillars_base_prices"),
   url: 'admin/garden_pillars_base_prices'
end
```

I use Rails 5.1.4 with ActiveAdmin 1.1.0

EDIT:

When I click on the link from the main admin page (`/admin`) the link in the header works fine. Yet when I click on the very same link from the `admin/garden_pillars_base_prices` page, I get the routing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url should start with `/`

it should be

```rb
url: '/admin/garden_pillars_base_prices'
```

Intead of

```rb
url: 'admin/garden_pillars_base_prices'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replacing url 'admin/garden_pillars_base_prices' with route from rake routes like admin_garden_pillars_base_prices_path ?

Comment: It throws an error. I don't thing you have access to those methods in an initializer.